# Problem when disconnecting a user in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with ASP.Net MVC regarding authentication. The user managed to login and log out with no problem but when I click the back button is in the browser on the watch still logged in !!!
Can someone help me!!!
I also remind you that I am not using the default authentication of Visual Studio

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var isValidUser = IsValidUser(model);

            if(isValidUser != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserMail, true); 
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Eror", "Invalid login attempt");
                return View();
            }
            
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }

 public User IsValidUser(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        using(var db = new DbCaimanContext())
        {
            User user = db.Users.Where(q => q.UserMail.Equals(model.UserMail) && q.Password.Equals(model.Password)).SingleOrDefault();

            if (user == null)
                return null;
            else
                return user;
        }
    }
```

And here is my disconnection method :

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Abandon();
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

Comment: Please give details of your authentication method, and a code example, e.g. how you log the user out.

Comment: I just updated my post

Comment: Have you tried Session.Clear(); before the Session.Abandon(); ?

Comment: no not yet i will do it right now...

Comment: It's always the same, the user's information remains visible and it gives the impression that the user is still connected
while it is indeed disconnected on the server side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear browser cache when user log off in asp.net using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306090/how-to-clear-browser-cache-when-user-log-off-in-asp-net-using-c) It's possible that what you see after pressing browser's back button is in local cache. You could disable cache for that page.

Comment: that's exactly what i want. Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 0):

In your Login Get Method

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main");// go to anywhere you want
        else
            return View();
    }
```